# Django+mysqlclient not closing database connections

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using 2 mysql database connections. After every page request in django, the connection count ( as displayed by `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Conn%'` increases by 2 each time.

Python 3.4.0
django 1.8.2
mysqlclient 1.3.6

( Both Windows and Linux seem to have the issue )

Initially i accessed the second database directly through MySQLdb but now i've switched to using `django.db.connections['...']` to access it.

This is my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myapp',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'analytics': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myapp_analytics',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
```

And these are the classes that i wrote to for easy usage:

```
import MySQLdb as DBConnector
import django
class DictCursorEmulator:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.cursor = connection.cursor()

    def _execute(self,query_str,query_args):
        self.cursor.execute(query_str,query_args)

    def fetchall(self):
        "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
        desc = self.cursor.description
        return [
            dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
            for row in self.cursor.fetchall()
        ]

    def fetchone(self):
        desc = self.cursor.description
        return dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))


#I probably should have used instance methods here but there's too much code to update ;_;
class DatabaseInterface:
    @classmethod
    def execute(self, queryStr, args):
        cursor = DictCursorEmulator(django.db.connections['analytics'])
        cursor._execute(queryStr,args)
        return cursor

    @classmethod
    def autocommit(cls, set_to):
        django.db.connections['analytics'].autocommit(set_to)


    @classmethod
    def commit(cls):
        django.db.connections['analytics'].commit()

    @classmethod
    def rollback(cls):
        django.db.connections['analytics'].rollback()
```

I've tried excluding the entire file but it still makes the connections count go up by 2, So i'm starting to think it's not a a problem with my code. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Update:** Apparently, `Connections` shows the total number of connections
Threads connected shows 2, which is expected. That solves my problem. I just had a lot of weird errors popping up on the DB side.

Comment: Which django version are you using? Do you use the [persistent-connections](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#persistent-connections) feature?

Comment: Django 1.8.2
Apparently, The connection variable shows the total number of connections.
So threads connected shows 2.
I guess that solves my problem now. I should have checked that before.